# SMTP Authentication Error had occured. How to resolve that?

Tags: python, smtp

Code is provided below:

```
import smtplib
s=smtplib.SMTP('127.0.0.1',587)
s.starttls()
s.login("EMAIL_ADDRESS@gmail.com","PASSWORD")
messsage="congrats"
s.sendmail('EMAIL_ADDRESS@gmail.com','RECIPIENT_ADDRESS@gmail.com',message)
s.quit()
```

**Error:**

> SMTPAuthenticationError:
>
> (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.

Comment: I hope you are not showing everybody your actual email address/password combination.

Comment: I've submitted an edit to remove potentially sensitive data.

Answer (score 1):

The SMTP server should be `smtp.gmail.com`, not `127.0.0.1`. `127.0.0.1` refers to `localhost` or the current server you are running on. So unless you happen to be running on Gmail's SMTP server, this will not work as you currently have it. **Of course, you must also use a correct email/password combination.**

Comment: Username and password are absolutely correct. I also edited this mistake of smtp.gmail.com and not 127.0.0.1. Then also I am getting the same error ?

Comment: I ran the code with the correct SMTP address  and substituted my Gmail address and password for yours and replaced `messsage` with `message` -- you have this misspelled -- and it worked. Of course, you are missing some headers so the message did not arrive with FROM, TO and SUBJECT specified. The fact is with your misspelling of `message`, the code you have posted is not runnable, so you never really posted what you are *actually* running (not counting hiding your email/password). You should go to gmail.com with your browser and login with your credentials and verify what you believe is real.